# Brand new CMT router bits won’t cut

Tags: router-bit

#### Summary

I recently purchased a set of 13 1/2” collet router bits from TayTools. I’m new to routing, and purchased the Kobalt router table. Setting everything up, I attempted to make a cut with a 3/4” straight bit in some pine. The cut traveled about 3/4” into the piece, and then ceased to move further. I repeated this with a dovetail bit and another straight bit to no avail.

### Description of Events

I’ll describe what happened with the 3/4” straight bit:

I locked the bit into the collet and submitted the router to the table. I aligned the fence along rulers that are etched into the table on either side of the bit housing (approximately 2 inches from the bit’s center). I turned on the router and allowed it to reach full speed. Using a Grr-ripper, I applied pressure toward the fence and down toward the table to secure it. Then, I slowly fed the piece of wood into the bit (end-grain first, but I also repeated this process in a cross-grain fashion). The bit seemed to struggle for the first ~3/4” cut, and then would not cut further. The wood started to scorch from the bit spinning in the same space for an extended period of time. I then stopped pushing because I felt the situation became dangerous.

This situation happened again with a dovetail bit, where I aligned the fence so that it passed over the center of the bit (i.e. 0” from the bit). The dovetail bit cut better than the 3/4, but struggled and caused massive tearout.

#### Conclusion

Any ideas what the issue could be? Since the bits have carbide tips, I don’t know how I could attempt to sharpen them. The router does not have a variable speed dial. Could it be the RPMs?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. I think you'll need to describe the circumstances in a little more detail, "ceased to move further" is pretty unequivocal but we weren't there so we can't visualise the sequence of events, e.g. I can't imagine it's the cause, but the bits didn't actually stop spinning did they? And there are other possibly relevant details.... it isn't that the two sides of the fence aren't aligned is it, so the leading corner of the wood hit the second half and couldn't progress further?

Comment: @Graphus Thank you for your reply. I’ll update the question to provide more detail.

Comment: BTW you can sharpen some carbide router bits but it's tricky to do well and maintaining balance is critical. Especially if you have limited sharpening experience it may be best to either buy new bits as needed, or (in the case of better quality pricier bits) send them out to be sharpened professionally. As a leisure woodworker barring an accident that damages an edge, or lots of cutting of very wearing material (particleboard, OSB, very hard hardwoods) you can expect months to *years* of service from your bits. These days this includes some cheap ones, which can be surprisingly decent.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I updated the question.

Comment: This might be an obvious question, but I have to ask: since we are cutting until we can't, are the chips being cleared properly? A router should make a mess of chips underneath it, and very few chips should be left in the void it cuts.

Comment: Also, another obvious question: you are taking light passes, correct? Like, you can't _really_ hog out a slot or even a deep chamfer in one go. Even in pine. Maybe especially in pine. At least, not without a good handle on feed speeds, and the ability to change the tool speed.

Comment: I find that confirming the "obvious" is important... When you're feeding the wood across the bit, you're starting with the wood on the right side of the bit and pushing it across to the left side as the exposed cutting edge of the bit is toward you, correct?

Answer (score 1):

After inspecting the bits, I believe all are completely dull. I suppose I’ll find someone to sharpen them/verify this.

Comment: Just to check, these were new right? And if so, the bits didn't have anything covering the working end?

Comment: My guess is that you actually have a set of CMT bits, which are distributed by Taylor Tools. They have a replacement guarantee you should take advantage of.  Graphus is reminding us that router bits often come in a sheath of clear vinyl they are dipped in during manufacturing, which you are to peel off carefully before use. It's hard to believe that a new set would be dull if you bought them from an official distributor (whether or not via Amazon, etc.)

Comment: Oops. didn't see the "CMT" in the title, as I often ignore titles.

Comment: @Graphus They were new. Unless there is something very difficult to see covering the end, I would say “No”, there is nothing covering the tools.

Comment: Thanks for that. If there were a coating it would be very evident, if there is a protective coating it often looks like the end of the bit has been dipped in wax. Anyway the bits being blunt straight from the factory is slightly bizarre, since CMT bits used to be highly regarded. In a set I can maybe accept one or two bits being under par due to the law of averages, but if they're all the same it indicates a massive slip in standards.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that this router is running backwards, or the infeed side of the table has been reversed -- that is the fence is on the "wrong" side. At any rate, CMT will replace those bits.

Comment: I am a novice woodworker and even moreso when it comes to routing. Feeling the edges of the router bits, there is no ‘bite’ as one typically feels with a sharp edge. I purchased a set of Skil bits from lowes (1/4” shank, versus the 1/2” CMT shank), and had better luck with the straight bit from Skil. 

I will add that the router I have is a Kobalt that came with the router table, and it runs at a continues 25,000RPM with no load. That could be contributing to the problem.

Comment: @jdv The router table makes setting the fence up on the incorrect side impossible. I wish that was the issue haha.

Comment: The sharpness issue with carbide is an interesting topic of its own. It is widely held that you can't get it truly sharp, not like steel can be sharp, and although that's exaggerated (few have ever tried, or take the time, to sharpen carbide beyond a certain point in part because of its extreme hardness) you can't expect the carbides on a typical router bit to be *sharp* sharp like you might expect to feel on a brand new kitchen knife. But it should still feel like there's a definite edge. Do you have a jeweller's loupe/strong magnifying lens? If the edges are blunt you'll be able to see them.

Comment: @jdv, I know it's been discounted by the OP but the fence on the wrong side would result in a climb cut wouldn't it?

Comment: @Graphus, That's true. I'm just trying to picture what is going wrong here, as dull-from-factory seems so unlikely.

Comment: The best RPM for a tool is based on the tools radius. In general, the larger the radius, the slower the speed. There are ways of figuring perfect RPM, but _in general_ you can hand-wave that bits under 1in want to be run at 24,000 RPM (+/- 1000 RPM will make no discernible difference). So only if the bit you choose is over 1in would you really have to care for this router. (You can get aftermarket speed controls for some routers.)

Comment: My curiosity is piqued, for sure. If you have a macro lens I'd _love_ to see pictures of the edges!

Comment: Then again, if a newish Freud or Skil bit of the same kind cuts without burning or lugging in the exact same situation, and the CMT bits do not, I guess I have to accept CMT messed up. Assuming you got your feed rate and cut depth at something reasonable.